# 2009 BMW 335i sedan

Tags: audio, bluetooth, 335i

Hello I recently bought a 2010 335i that was built early in 2010 and I don't have audio Bluetooth but I heard if you have a usb in the center console you could do a system update but I don't have one in there I have one in my glove box am I still able to upgrade my stereo that way I could have Bluetooth audio? I don't have idrive either I do have navigation and all the others though

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe adding the A2DP profile is possible on older bluetooth integrations, especially without iDrive. The USB does give you some options, but they're not bluetooth-based.

You can do what I did with my 2006 330xi:

I got a little bluetooth box which takes a usb power input and has an aux output, and I have it in my center console. Plug that into the cigarette lighter and aux input in the center console and just pair to it. If you get one that specifically does *not* support calling you'll be able to pair to your car's phone and the audio device simultaneously.

I also added a remote so I can control the music without touching my phone. That acts as a keyboard using bluetooth, so it also pairs without affecting the other two devices.

The only downside to this setup is I must press the pair button each time I get into the car on the bluetooth box, but I'm sure there are some which don't need that, and it's really not too bad.